# Issue while using ffill in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to drag values of excel in a column to empty column after that value.I am using ffill, its working but behaving differently. Please see the input and output and what i want.

Input:

```
col1
 a
 na
 na
 na
 b
 na
 na
 na
 c
 na
 d
 na
 na
```

my code on this:

```
df[['col1']]=df[['col1']].ffill()
```

output i am getting:

```
col1
 a
 a
 a
 a
 b
 b
 b
 b
 c
 d
 d
 d
```

After execution of my code it is dragging all vales to the empty spaces more then one empty space but
if empty space is one its not dragging.

Comment: are your blank values actually `NaN`s?

Comment: Yes  that empty space is NaN .

Comment: I can not reproduce your error, it is behaving well if I try. Can you provide a complete piece of code that we can run to get this error?

Comment: try `df[col] = df[col].fillna(df[col].ffill())`

Comment: I have observed one thing that my column has one value like E$ , its not dragging E$ to next line and after this only i am seeing this weird behavior, before it everthing is fine.

Comment: I would just like to add that when you read in your data from a csv using `pd.read_csv`, you can use `na_values = 'na'` to set 'na' as a `NaN` in pandas. Then follow the advice from @Datanovice. See (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).